# Running ndk-gdb with package not found error on motorola phone

Tags: android, gdb, android-ndk, remote-debugging, android-ndk-r5

I have a C++ Android application that I'm trying to debug with ndk-gdb.  The application does use multiple threads, but supposedly r5 of the ndk supports multiple threads.  Also, I'm not even getting to the point where gdb starts up.  I run the command:

```
ndk-gdb --start --force --verbose
```

It then finds the proper path for the ndk and sdk (or at least adb), and the needed ABIs and whatnot.

```
$ ndk-gdb --start --force --verbose
Android NDK installation path: /home/leif/eclipse/android-ndk-r5b
Using default adb command: /home/leif/eclipse/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.26
Using final ADB command: '/home/leif/eclipse/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb'
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: net.leifandersen.mobile.android.marblemachine
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
Device API Level: 10
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi
```

It then looks for gdb server, and finds it, including the proper PID, followed by starting the activity.

But then, it tells me that the the package cannot be found:

```
Setup network redirection
## COMMAND: /home/leif/eclipse/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb shell run-as <package name> lib/gdbserver +debug-socket --attach 16040
## COMMAND: /home/leif/eclipse/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb forward tcp:5039 localfilesystem:run-as: Package '<package name>' is unknown/debug-socket
```

It then spits out what you would get if you improperly use adb (the help file), followed by:

```
ERROR: Could not setup network redirection to gdbserver?
       Maybe using --port=<port> to use a different TCP port might help?
run-as: Package '<package name>' is unknown
```

I looked into /data/system/packages.list, and yes, my apk is most certainly in there, and the location it's pointing to is correct on the file system.  So that's not the problem.

This tutorial: http://vilimpoc.org/blog/2010/09/23/hello-gdbserver-a-debuggable-jni-example-for-android/ recommends deleting and reinstalling, as well as cleaning your eclipse build.

I didn't use eclipse to build the package, but I did clean everything out and compile from scratch, deleted, and reinstalled to no luck.

Has anyone had similar problems, and how did you resolve them?  Thank you.

Edit: Oh, and I have tried a different port to no avail, there does not appear to be anything on 5039 (the default port) anyway.  And afaik, I don't have any firewalls blocking that connection.  I'm developing on Ubuntu 11.04 as well.

Edit2: Hmm...it looks like with the new ndk (r5c), the error message has now changed too:

```
ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that
       your installed application is debuggable?
```

And yes, debuggable is set to true in the manifest, and all of the native code is built with:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS           := -Wall -g
LOCAL_LDFLAGS          := -Wl,-Map,xxx.map
```

Comment: Does '$ adb shell run-as net.leifandersen.mobile.android.marblemachine ls' work?

Comment: Nope, I get: run-as: Package 'net.leifandersen.mobile.android.marblemachine' is unknown, also, it looks like there is a bug report for this sort of thing, but the package isn't three levels deep: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13965.  Also, as I said, the package is still listed in /data/system/packages.list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
run-as: Package 'net.leifandersen.mobile.android.marblemachine' is unknown
```

Thus, unfortunately, your device is not able to be used with ndk-gdb, because run-as doesn't work. If you want to use that device, you must have root privilege.

**EDITED:**

Modify ndk-gdb script to get rid of the dependency of run-as. It works only on root privilege ('adb shell whoami' should be 'root').

```
--- ndk-gdb 2011-02-24 16:55:07.000000000 +0900
+++ ndk-gdb-root    2011-06-09 08:35:04.000000000 +0900
@@ -465,7 +465,7 @@
 log "Using app out directory: $APP_OUT"

 # Find the <dataDir> of the package on the device
-DATA_DIR=`adb_shell run-as $PACKAGE_NAME /system/bin/sh -c pwd`
+DATA_DIR="/data/data/$PACKAGE_NAME"
 log "Found data directory: '$DATA_DIR'"
 if [ $? != 0 -o -z "$DATA_DIR" ] ; then
     echo "ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that"
@@ -543,7 +543,7 @@

 # Launch gdbserver now
 DEBUG_SOCKET=debug-socket
-run $ADB_CMD shell run-as $PACKAGE_NAME lib/gdbserver +$DEBUG_SOCKET --attach $PID &
+run $ADB_CMD shell "(cd $DATA_DIR; lib/gdbserver +$DEBUG_SOCKET --attach $PID)" &
 if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
     echo "ERROR: Could not launch gdbserver on the device?"
     exit 1
```

Comment: With root privileges, how would I go about fixing the problem (or even figuring out what the problem is in the first place)?  Thank you.

Comment: (Well, not on r5c, but r5b works fine, and I would imagine that a similar edit would work for r5c).

Comment: "Thus, unfortunately, your device is not able to be used with ndk-gdb, because run-as doesn't work. If you want to use that device, you must have root privilege." - No, there is actually a bug in run-as.  You do not need root privileges.  See my answer.

Comment: You Sir are my hero. Ballads should be sang about you!

Comment: run-as is apparently completely broken on 4.3: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373 . The 'FutureRelease' status means that the next Android version should resolve it, presumably the upcoming 4.4.

Comment: Thank you @jrr I have nexus4 4.3 updated - and am having same issue. Figured this out after 2 days reading your comment. So to do native debugging Either I root my nexus4 and try or apply android 4.3 fresh image (loose all data on handset) or wait a little for android 4.4 update.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug with run-as, it will fail if you have too many apps installed.  I was able to work around this problem by removing some apps from my Evo 4G.  I found this in the NDK discussion groups - http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/ae9e8d5fe2716ae6?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today with Samsung Galaxy S running MIUI rom. ndk-gdb always reported "Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that your installed application is debuggable?"

It turned out the reason is that run-as not working due to /data/data symlink. Cyanogen is used in the customized ROM. Removing the symbolic link and move all files from /datadata to /data/data solved the problem.

Cyanogen 2.3 fix:

ndk-gdb relies on the 'run-as' command, which itself makes a number of checks on the /data/data directory. In Cyanogen 2.3, it's a symlink, and run-as fails with a cryptic message, and ndk-gdb fails in return with [2]:

```
ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that
       your installed application is debuggable?
```

A work-around is to recreate /data/data with symlink :

```
cd /data/data /datadata.break-run-as
mkdir -m 771 /data/data/
chown system: v
mv /datadata/* /data/data/
```

---

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android_NDK

http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/27657-run-as-not-working-due-to-datadata-symlink/

Hope it helps others with similar issue. Check to see if run-as works as expected or not. It's not because your binary is not debuggable. ndk-gdb's error message is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and running:

```
adb shell run-as com.mypackagename /system/bin/sh -c pwd
```

would output:

```
run-as: Package 'com.mypackagename' has corrupt installation
```

fix was to uninstall on device then reinstall from command line via:

```
adb install MyApkFile.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem and discovered that it can be caused by short package names!

When testing on an Android 2.2 system with an application that had a package with 3 levels (e.g: a.b.c) ndk-gdb would not work. Changing the package to have 4 or more levels (e.g. a.b.c.d) or running on Android 2.3 or later resolved the issue.

see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13965 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is still another posibility for this problem to occur: if you have previously installed your application as a system app (in /system/app), uninstalled it and then installed it once again as a normal application. In that case it is posible that there is still some files remaining that your application cannot access because it has no permissions.

I solved it by uninstalling my application and manually removing every piece of information related to it (with adb shell and root privileges). As far as I know, that comprises:

- Everything under /data/data/<your app package>
- The file named /data/dalvik-cache/* <your app package>*

After installing it again, I was able to debug the application again.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using Samsung Galaxy S4/... and got 4.4.2 (latest stock rom - by now at all countries) - you got screwed! Samsung bug. So root as explained in one of the answers above, or get another device...
Another solution is to revert to Android 4.2.2 (not 4.4.2) - pre 4.3 version which started this issue.