# Android NDK: native code backtrace in LogCat only show two frames

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I encounter a native code crash, the backtrace in LogCat has only the top most two frame, I can't see other frames, which makes debugging quite frustrating.
Is there any way I can see more stack trace frames in LogCat?

Comment: What are the frames?  What version of Android?  I've had issues in the past with functions marked "noreturn" because they don't have to preserve the link register.

Comment: @fadden frames are the list of function calling chain, you can take Android 4.2 in specific, but I see most Android version has this problem.

Comment: I'm asking what are the functions shown in the frames, i.e. do you see `abort` or `_div0` or is it code from your library?

Comment: @fadden sorry I'v misunderstood you, those frames are normal frames which are exactly my functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for gdb for native application debuging on android [Generate core dump in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186365/generate-core-dump-in-android)
hope this will provide even more info. I got this [incomplete backtrace in logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633866/incomplete-backtrace-in-logcat) here. 
Refer here for more http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/
Hope I got your question right.

Comment: Although debugging is a way to solve this, I need the stack trace in the log so that if user crashes, I can get a report of the crash stack trace.