# run-as says 'package is unknown' after upgrading Android to 4.3

Tags: android, adb, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a simple script that downloads database from phone to my PC
it uses 'run-as', it worked well, but now, run-as says 'package is unknown'
my application is installed on device, nothing changed, just Android was updated to 4.3

Do you have the same problems? how to bypass this or resolve ?

Comment: I think it's because of this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373

Comment: just had this on lollipop :-( https://gist.github.com/ligi/d8fe38701eb00f8514ae )

Comment: From my tests, it works on Android 6

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the missing run-as problem when the Galaxy S4 released without it. We were using run-as to start a gdbserver for app debugging.

We worked around the issue by starting gdbserver as an Android service. More details at [run-as Package 'a.b.c' is unknown - Galaxy S4 Jellybean or Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219906/run-as-package-a-b-c-is-unknown-galaxy-s4-jellybean)

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little my script, but it needs phone to be rooted

%adb% shell "su root cp /data/data/%PACKAGE%/databases/%DB%  /sdcard/my/%DB%"

%adb% pull /sdcard/my/%DB% db

Answer (score 0):

Just spent half a day faced the same problem on my Nexus 7 (800x1280). 
The issue described here, as user408952 mentioned:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373

Answer #32 from the link above worked for me: I've installed 4.3 factory image and everything works. No root needed!