# Visual Studio 2015 fails to run Android app on some devices

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

While trying to use Visual Studio 2015 (community edition) to compile and run a simple Android app (the Hello World example you get when you create a new empty Android project in fact) I ran into the apparently [well known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032234/run-as-says-package-is-unknown-after-upgrading-android-to-4-3?lq=1) problem that "run-as" does not work on some Android devices. In fact it does not work on any of those I tried running different versions of KitKat and Lollipop.

After successfully deploying the app, Visual Studio 2015 reports "Unable to start debugging. Android command "run-as" failed. Package com.Android1 is unknown"

I do not want to root the device to change the packages.list attributes, but I can successfully use "am start com.Android1/.Android1" from adb to run the app.

I would therefore like to modify the scripts kicking off the app execution in Visual Studio 2015 to use "am" instead of "run-as", but despite browsing through settings, makefiles, and scripts containing references to "run-as" I could not find where it's done. Is it possible to do it, and how? Or is there an alternative solution that does not require rooting the device?