# Unable to attach ndk-gdb to android process

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-gdb

I have two processes in the Android application- main application process and a remote service process.
The native libraries are loaded from the remote service process.

I want to debug the native library code. 
The application is debuggable. The native library was built from Windows command-line using ndk-build. In Android.mk, -g -ggdb flag was used for this library.
I am running ndk-gdb from cygwin.

Test device: Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.2

Error line: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

In the verbose information, I see that gdbserver is trying to attach to process id of the main application process. Should it matter that the library is loaded from a remote process within this application.

Detailed ndk-gdb run information-
    $ ndk-gdb --verbose --force
    Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/c/work/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9
    Using default adb command: /cygdrive/c/work/android/sdk/android-sdk_r10-windows/android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/adb
    ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
    Using ADB flags:
    Using JDB command: /cygdrive/c/program files (x86)/java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/jdb
    Using auto-detected project path: .
    Found package name: [application-pkg-name]
    ABIs targetted by application: armeabi
    Device API Level: 17
    Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
    Compatible device ABI: armeabi
    Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
    Using toolchain prefix: /cygdrive/c/work/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
    Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi
    Found debuggable flag: true
    Found device gdbserver: /data/data/[applcation-pkg-name]/lib/gdbserver
    Found data directory: '/data/data/[applcation-pkg-name]'
    Found running PID: 17890
    Launched gdbserver succesfully.
    Setup network redirection
    ## COMMAND: adb_cmd shell run-as [applcation-pkg-name] lib/gdbserver +debug-socket --attach 17890
    ## COMMAND: adb_cmd forward tcp:5039 localfilesystem:/data/data/[applcation-pkg-name]/debug-socket
    Attached; pid = 17890   [Comment: This pid is for the main application process]
    Listening on Unix socket debug-socket
    ## COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process obj/local/armeabi/app_process
    493 KB/s (9592 bytes in 0.019s)
    Pulled app_process from device/emulator.
    ## COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/linker obj/local/armeabi/linker
    1165 KB/s (63244 bytes in 0.053s)
    Pulled linker from device/emulator.
    ## COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/lib/libc.so obj/local/armeabi/libc.so
    2442 KB/s (297608 bytes in 0.119s)
    Pulled libc.so from device/emulator.
    /cygdrive/c/work/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Couple of side notes that could be helpful-
1) If I run the ndk-gdb command without --force, it gives me error that Another debug session is running. Although the gdb prompt came out during the last run.
2) On Android 4.3, with the same application and setup, I get error that "Could not extract package's data directory"

Comment: Is this related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219906/run-as-package-a-b-c-is-unknown-galaxy-s4-jellybean-or-android-4-3