# Android ndk debug on sumsung phones

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, gdb, ndk-gdb

some days ago, I bought a phone Sumsung s4.then I find that I couldn't use ndk debug on the phone. I have surching lots of infomation , but not get a solution.
The question is Sumsung have changed some code for the system./data/system/packages.list is used by 'run-as' both to get the data directory for an app, and to start gdbserver on the device.  Most samsung phones have this moved to /dbdata/system/packages.list, but 'run-as' wasn't rebuilt to reflect this change, and throws an error.  So, the ndk-gdb script can't connect to these phones.
so please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The gdb (and invoking script) built into the [Apportable SDK](http://www.apportable.com/) has a workaround for the ndk-gdb run-as issue on the Samsung S4 (and many Android 4.3 phones)

More details available at [run-as Package 'a.b.c' is unknown - Galaxy S4 Jellybean or Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219906/run-as-package-a-b-c-is-unknown-galaxy-s4-jellybean-or-android-4-3)