# ERROR: Package cookbook.chapter3 is not debuggable (ndk-gdb)

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am reading `Android Native Development Kit Cookbook`. And there are sample codes in each chapter. Current chapter is dedicated to `Debugging an Android NDK application with
NDK GDB`. But I have problems with it. The cookbook requires that `AndroidManifest.xml` has the `android:debuggable` attribute of the `<application>`element set to `true`. But when I set it `true` or `false` Eclipse complains with an error. I have read that `android:debuggable=true` is not mandatory, you can just do `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1` and app will be debuggable. So I have omitted setting `debuggable` flag in `Manifest` and just build the app. Then deployed the app on device run it and called `ndk-gdb` from terminal. But I got this message:

> $ ndk-gdb
>
> ERROR: Package cookbook.chapter3 is not debuggable ! You can
>   fix that in two ways:
>
> - Rebuilt with the NDK_DEBUG=1 option when calling 'ndk-build'.
> - Modify your manifest to set android:debuggable attribute to "true",
>
>   then rebuild normally.

How to overcome this problems (the flag in manifest and achieve debugging)? Please help me to debug my test project. I am just learning.

Comment: If you are running Android version 4.2 or 4.3 something then it might be because of an Android bug. I had the same issue and when I tried `adb shell run-as $MY_PACKAGE_NAME` I got `Package '$MY_PACKAGE_NAME' is unknown`. Somehow I think ndk-gdb is using run-as and thats why it doesn't work. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219906/run-as-package-a-b-c-is-unknown-galaxy-s4-jellybean-or-android-4-3) post for more information ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23986724/632951