# Adb copy from device

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to copy a file from my device to my desktop using the following adb command:

```
adb shell run-as peachss.test.inspect pull  /data/data/peachss.test.inspect/files/Inspection.2.xml %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\
```

But it just say that Package 'peachss.test.inspect' is Unknown, but I can see that it is installed on the device

Edit 1:
Forgot to mention, I am using the S4-Mini with Android 4 or 4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a recognized Android bug.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219906/run-as-package-a-b-c-is-unknown-galaxy-s4-jellybean-or-android-4-3) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373)

The issue is related to the use of "run-as", not "pull", is it totally needed for what you want to achieve?

Hope this help.s

Comment: If I do not use run-as then I get the message 'Permission Denied'

Comment: of course, you are trying to access a private file, that should not be a problem if your phone is rooted

Comment: I managed to get a work around by adding code to my app to copy the files to the public folders and then update the installed app. This worked for me